# wrong output when code runs problem with linked list?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

Upon running the code below i get the output

NAME: (null)  | GPA: 0.000000 | YEAR: (NULL)

are the linked lists not implemented correctly? I am currently using a makefile and bringing in a test.data file with names and gpa and senior/ect..

Ollie     2.9   freshmen
John      3.2   senior  
Julie     2.2   freshmen
Joe       1.8   freshmen
Mary      3.8   senior  
Sue       3.4   junior  
Jane      2.7   senior  
Bob       2.8   senior  
Fred      3.2   freshmen
Bill      3.3   junior

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "students.h"

Student *top = NULL;
Student *temp, *temp1, *temp2;

// Creates the entire linked list from the file.                                                                                                                           
// Should call readNext and push                                                                                                                                           
// Returns head of the linked list                                                                                                                                         
Student *buildStudentList()
{
  Student *p;
  p = readNext();
  push(&top, p);

  return top;  //TODO: Change return                                                                                                                                       
}

//Read a single line from standard input and return a student structure located on the heap                                                                                
Student *readNext()
{
  Student *s =(Student*)  malloc(sizeof(Student));

  scanf("%s", s -> name);
  scanf("%f", &s -> gpa);
  scanf("%s", s -> year);
  s->next = NULL;

return s; //TODO: Change return                                                                                                                                            
}
//Return a student structure stored on the heap                                                                                                                            
Student *makeStudent(char *name, float gpa, char *year)
{

Student *s =(Student*) malloc(sizeof(Student));

s -> name = name;

s -> gpa = gpa;

s -> year = year;

s -> next = NULL;


return s;  //TODO: Change return                                                                                                                                           
}

//insert a new student node at the head of the linked list                                                                                                                 
void push(Student **list, Student *student)
{
top = *list;

student -> next = top;

top = student;

}
//Insert a student node in the desired position on the linked list                                                                                                         
void insert(Student *list, Student *s, int position)
{
  int i;
top = list;
temp = top;
for(i = 1; i < position -1; i++)
    {
   temp = temp -> next;
}
if(temp == NULL)
    {
       //blank                                                                                                                                                             
    }
else
    {
   s -> next = temp -> next;
   temp -> next = s;
}
}
//Displays contents of a single student structure                                                                                                                          
void display(Student *s){

printf("NAME:%s  | GPA: %f       | YEAR:%s
", s -> name, s-> gpa, s -> year);


}

//Displays contents of the entire linked list                                                                                                                              
void displayAll(Student *list)
{

temp = list;

while(temp != NULL)
{
  display(temp);
  temp = temp -> next;
 }

}
//Delete all data allocated on the heap before terminating program                                                                                                         
void cleanUp(Student *list)
{
temp1 = list;
temp2 = temp1 -> next;

while(temp1 != NULL)
{
   free(temp1);
   temp1 = temp2;
 }

 if(temp2 != NULL)
   {
      temp2 = temp2 -> next;
   }

}
//Main function tests your functions.                                                                                                                                      
int main()
{
printf("Program Started
");

//Construct Linked List from Standard Input                                                                                                                                
Student *list = buildStudentList();

//Insert a new student in desired position                                                                                                                                 
Student *s = makeStudent("Max",3.0, "senior");
insert(list, s, 3);

//Display entire linked list                                                                                                                                               
displayAll(list);

//Free all heap memory                                                                                                                                                     
cleanUp(list);

    printf("Program Successful Exit
");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Please format this code properly. It is hardly readable.

Comment: Could you convince us that your scanfs work? Your code seems very  trusting, not to check the return values.

Comment: Did you do some debugging? Either use a debugger or several paranoid checks and output of relevant data. Try to find out which function fails. The creation, the reading, the output...

Comment: The fields `name` and `year` of `Student` are either `char` array or pointers. (You are not showing it.) If they were arrays, the assignment in `makeStudent` would give a compiler error. But if they are pointers, you never allocate for them before calling `scanf` in `readNext`. That causes undefined behavior.

Comment: are they not allocated with the use of malloc(sizeof(Student) line?

Comment: @MB2204 The pointers are, but they will not be pointing to anything. The memory for the strings needs to still be allocated and the pointers in `Student` need to be set to point to the memory allocated for the strings.

Comment: You can't embed newlines in strings. When you need a newline in a string, use the `\n` escape sequence (e.g.) `printf("hello world\n");`

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post your `struct` definition, I had to guess whether (e.g.) `name` was `char *name;` or (e.g. `char name[100];`). Within the code, it used it as a pointer.

So ...

Your `readNext` and `makeStudent` don't allocate space for the strings (`char *` pointers) `name` and `year`, so they're probably segfaulting.

`insert` takes `Student *list` when it really needs `Student **list`.

IMO, you should have a separate `List` type to avoid confusion (that has a single element: `Student *head;`). So, wherever you have `Student *list`, you replace it with `List *list`

When you do that, you don't have to pass down `Student **` [a double star] pointer when you mean a list. Using `list->head` is a lot easier and more descriptive than `*list`.

Also, be consistent. Some functions take `Student **list` if they *modify* the list [they *have* to]. Others use `Student *list`, but they should be consistent as well.

No need for the various *global* scope temp variables. These should be function scoped and use more descriptive names.

Your `insert` has issues. It will *orphan* the node it's trying to insert if *no* position match is found (e.g. insert at position 99 in your example). Usual is to insert at tail or return an error code. Also, it wasn't totally clear what `position` meant [to me], because of the code you had. It could have been "insert before" or "insert after" the Nth node.

You *can't* insert a literal newline in a double quoted string. So, use the `\n` escape sequence (e.g.) `printf("hello world\n");`

Also, functions that take *no* arguments should use `void` (e.g.) instead of `int main()`, use `int main(void)`.

Here's a cleaned up version of your code, incorporating what I've mentioned above:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//#include "students.h"
typedef struct student Student;
struct student {
    Student *next;
    float gpa;
    char *name;
    char *year;
};

typedef struct list {
    Student *head;
} List;

//insert a new student node at the head of the linked list
void
push(List *list, Student *student)
{

    student->next = list->head;
    list->head = student;
}

//Return a student structure stored on the heap
Student *
makeStudent(char *name, float gpa, char *year)
{

    Student *s = (Student *) malloc(sizeof(Student));
    s->name = strdup(name);
    s->gpa = gpa;
    s->year = strdup(year);
    s->next = NULL;

    return s;
}

//Read a single line from standard input and return a student structure located on the heap
Student *
readNext(void)
{
    char name[1000];
    float gpa;
    char year[1000];
    Student *s = NULL;

    int count = scanf("%s %f %s",name,&gpa,year);

    if (count == 3) {
        printf("readNext: name='%s' gpa=%g year='%s'\n",name,gpa,year);
        s = makeStudent(name,gpa,year);
    }

    return s;
}

// Creates the entire linked list from the file.
// Should call readNext and push
// Returns head of the linked list
List *
buildStudentList(List *list)
{
    Student *p;

    while (1) {
        p = readNext();
        if (p == NULL)
            break;
        push(list, p);
    }

    return list;
}

//Insert a student node in the desired position on the linked list
int
insert(List *list, Student *s, int position)
{
    Student *cur;
    Student *prev;
    int i;
    int goflg;

    //position -= 1;

#if 0
    i = 1;  // insert before Nth position
#else
    i = 0;  // insert after Nth position
#endif
    prev = NULL;

    for (cur = list->head;  (cur != NULL) && (i < position);
        ++i, cur = cur->next) {
        prev = cur;
    }

    // this may not be needed -- usual is to insert at tail if position is not
    // found -- this will orphan the node to be inserted
#if 0
    goflg = (i == position);
#else
    goflg = 1;
#endif

    if (goflg) {
        s->next = cur;
        if (prev != NULL)
            prev->next = s;
        else
            list->head = s;
    }

    return goflg;
}

//Displays contents of a single student structure
void
display(Student *s)
{

    printf("NAME:%s  | GPA: %f       | YEAR:%s\n", s->name, s->gpa, s->year);

}

//Displays contents of the entire linked list
void
displayAll(List *list)
{
    Student *temp = list->head;

    while (temp != NULL) {
        display(temp);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

}

//Delete all data allocated on the heap before terminating program
void
cleanUp(List *list)
{
    Student *cur;
    Student *next;

    for (cur = list->head;  cur != NULL;  cur = next) {
        next = cur->next;
        free(cur->name);
        free(cur->year);
        free(cur);
    }

    list->head = NULL;
}

//Main function tests your functions.
int
main(void)
{
    List top = { NULL };
    List *list;

    printf("Program Started\n");

    //Construct Linked List from Standard Input
    list = buildStudentList(&top);

    //Insert a new student in desired position
    Student *s = makeStudent("Max", 3.0, "senior");
    insert(list, s, 3);

    //Display entire linked list
    displayAll(list);

    //Free all heap memory
    cleanUp(list);

    printf("Program Successful Exit\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```